# how to deal with DOM-specific stuff in an itemController?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have an Ember DS.Model of Categories which have many Measures, and these are displayed in a bootstrap accordion, where the category name is the panel header, and there are selectable buttons for each measure. In my template I have a chevron that's either pointing right or down depending on whether that accordion panel is open/closed. I'd like to respond to the bootstrap open/close event for the accordion, which would be the `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events, and toggle the icon in the panel title between `glyphicon-chevron-right` and `glyphicon-chevron-down`.

My icon is within an itemController:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="measureSelectors">
  {{#each itemController='dashboard-category'}}
    <!-- ... -->
    <i class="panel-chevron glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    <!-- ... -->
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I assume I can only respond to the bootstrap event within a view, but I'm not sure how to wire a view with an itemController. How do I listen to the event and change the class?

There are other cases as well where I need to do DOM-specific stuff (e.g., call a jQuery function, load a d3 visualization) within an itemController, so I'm looking for basic strategies I can apply in different cases. I was hoping that I could just create an `App.DashboardCategoryView` class and that would work, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use render, it will wrap it in a view and controller associated with the template passed in.

```
{{#each }}
  {{render 'dashboard-category' this}}
{{/each}}
```

Would use `DashboardCategoryView` and `DashboardCategory` controller and pass this in as the model for the controller.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/muzeri/1/edit